# mongodb Unable to create/open lock file

Tags: permissions, mongodb

I installed `mongodb`:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

Tried to run it:

```
mongod
```

Runs into this error:

```
Mon Aug 21 20:46:44 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open 
lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
```

But the access rights must be fixed by now:

```
makan@blah:~$ls -hal /data/db/
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Aug 21 19:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Aug 21 19:56 ..
```

and:

```
makan@blah:~$ls -hal /data/
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Aug 21 19:56 db
```

So why can't mongodb open/create the lock file?

Comment: As per the error message .. have you checked if `mongod` is already running? Try `sudo service mongod status`.

Comment: Yepp checked! It is NOT running. Actually now setting the access rights to 'drwxrwxrwx', solved the problem. But why?

Comment: From the question description it seems you are running `mongod` from your own account, so the user would be  `makan`. The usual way to start/stop `mongod` would be using the service definition, which runs as the user and group `mongodb`: [`sudo service mongod start`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb). The service uses a configuration file (`/etc/mongod.conf`) and a data directory which should already have the correct permissions after installation (`/var/lib/mongodb`).

Comment: Thanks! If you add that as the answer it would be accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question description it appears you are running `mongod` from your own account (user: `makan`).

Your invocation of `mongod` without specifying a configuration file or `--dbpath` would require this user to have read/write permissions for the default dbpath directory (`/data/db`). Since `/data/db` is only writable by user `mongodb`, a permission error is expected when `mongod` tries to write a file running with the permissions of `makan`:

> lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating

The usual way to start/stop `mongod` is using the service definition, which runs as the user and group `mongodb` via [`sudo service mongod start`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#start-mongodb).

The service uses a configuration file (`/etc/mongod.conf`) and a data directory  (`/var/lib/mongodb`) which should already have the correct permissions after installation.